# How can I represent four variables in a highcharter treemap?

Tags: r, treemap, r-highcharter

I would like to create an interactive treemap with r-highcharter that includes four variables. So far I am only able to include three variables with the following approach:

```
library(highcharter)
        
set.seed(42)
n <- 12
dat <- data.frame(sector = factor(rep(LETTERS[1:4], n/4)),
                          ticker = rep(letters[1:12], 1),
                          weight = sample(1:10, n, replace = TRUE),
                          performance = sample(1:400, n, replace = TRUE))

print(dat)

   sector ticker weight performance
1       A      a      6         114
2       B      b      2         262
3       C      c      5         390
4       D      d      4         130
5       A      e      2         372
6       B      f      8           3
7       C      g      2         374
8       D      h      3         258
9       A      i      8         358
10      B      j      7         186
11      C      k      1         138
12      D      l      5          40

hchart(
  data_to_hierarchical(
    dat, c(sector, ticker), weight),
  type = "treemap"
)
```

The result is a treemap with three variables. The factor variable sector is represented by color, the character variable ticker by tiles and the numeric variable weight by size of tiles, see image [Treemap with three variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/givgY.jpg).

I would also like to include the numeric variable performance through the brightness of the color (min performance = bright, max performance = dark). Is there a way to do this?